# Heroku Basic Authentication of Gatsby App

Tags: heroku, gatsby

I have a Gatsby app that I've deployed to Heroku and I'd like to enable basic auth to restrict access to the whole app. Is this possible on Heroku with Gatsby?

Comment: I recommend to check out something like AWS Cognito, Auth0, Passport or some other auth solution/provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by implementing onCreateDevServer in Gatsby-node.js and adding express-basic-auth to the project.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider setting up a rest-api on heroku like this one here https://github.com/smakosh/not-todo-api/ and retrieve the token from your front end